# Using Nested Enum as Parameter in Seperate Package

Tags: java, enums, package

New to java and have a question related to packages.

I like to keep objects organized in namespaces and ran into a problem with enums that I cannot figure out.

Say I have a nested enum like this:

```
package Project;
public class Foo
{
    public enum Bar { One, Two, Three };
}
```

I want to do something like this

```
package Project.Attributes;
public class Foo
{
    public setBar( Project.Foo.Bar bar ) {}
}
```

But I am getting name conflicts and unknown package 'Foo' errors.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: for the record - your code above still does not compile. Next time provide real examples, especially when the question is about compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work after below corrections

1. semicolon after the package declaration
2. add void return type for setBar(...) method

One more suggestion is to use small case for package names.

```
package project;

public class Foo
{
    public enum Bar {
        One, Two, Three
    };
}


package project.attributes;

public class Foo
{
    public void setBar(project.Foo.Bar bar)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I just tried using javac to compile it and it worked just fine.  I guess netbeans is just misconfigured and does not know how to recognize the folder structures or something.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a semicolon at the end of the first line. And use lowercase letters for package names

Comment: well yes this is not exactly a working example, just a quick overview of my real project.  Do the package names really HAVE to be lowercase?